# Twitter Photo Card Pulling

Tags: javascript, python, html, twitter, flask

I'm trying to make a Twitter Photo Card which uses HTML meta Tags.

The first problem is, the tag looks something like this

```
<meta property="twitter:image" id="photo" content="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&chld=000000|15|h|FFFFFF|_|I+didnt+want+to+be+embarrassed%2C+so+I+claimed+that+I+had+a%7Clot+of+work+to+do.|||" />
```

Notice: there is an ampersand (&) in the url. When running it through the Twitter validator, it changes the `&` to `&amp;`. This makes the url invalid. So does `%26` (the code for an &).

Next, the content currently is virtually a placeholder. I'm passing a url from Flask to JavaScript `document.getElementById("photo").content = {{ imageurl|safe }}` which works (I check the source code of the loaded page). But the Twitter Photo Card validator pulls the placeholder, and not the updated one.

How do I fix both of these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&amp;` is a *HTML escape* because a `&` on it's own is the marker for the start of an escape. In other words, *it is normal and correct* to use `&amp;` in your HTML source for the character.

Take a look at this HTML:

```html
<a href="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_text_outline&amp;chld=000000|15|h|FFFFFF|_|I+didnt+want+to+be+embarrassed%2C+so+I+claimed+that+I+had+a%7Clot+of+work+to+do.|||">Correct link with &amp;amp; character in the URL</a>
```

Note that the `&` has been escaped as `&amp;` in the `href` attribute. If you look at the link in your browser (using a [JSFiddle live example](http://jsfiddle.net/X3dNt/) for instance), you'll notice that your browser has correctly interpreted the escaped ampersand for you. When you click the URL, it *works*.

The same applies to the `content` attribute on your Twitter `meta` tag. Twitter will extract the parameter *taking into account HTML escapes*.

You need to generate the twitter card attribute directly, not using JS, as the Twitter crawler will not execute Javascript:

```
<meta property="twitter:image" id="photo" content="{{ imageurl }}" />
```

Note that *Jinja2* will then escape the URL correctly, including replacing `&` with `&amp;`, provided you don't use `|safe` here, so that it'll actually escape it properly.

Also, you cannot use `chart.apis.google.com` urls in Twitter photo cards, because Google specifically [disallows robots from accessing the site](http://chart.apis.google.com/robots.txt). Twitter will not accept `chart.apis.google.com` URLs as they want to download the image for resizing but will also honour the `robots.txt` rules set out by Google.

Comment: That all makes sense, except the crawler then reads the `{{ imageurl| safe }}` as blank ("").

Comment: @John: and what is the *HTML produced* for that then?

Comment: The code is this `<meta property="twitter:image" content="{{ imageurl|safe }}"/>`, the crawler reads it as this `<meta property="twitter:image" content=""/>`, ahhh..this is the problem...the source code looks like this on the website `<meta property="twitter:image" id="photo" content="" http:="" chart.apis.google.com="" chart?chst="d_text_outline&amp;chld=000000|20|h|FFFFFF|_|hellooooooo||||||&quot;&quot;">`

Comment: The content is lost in the source code. How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: That is certainly not how Jinja2 would render the tag. Can you look *in your browser view source option* or use a command line tool like `curl` to get the rendered output. What is the actual text produced?

Comment: Whoops. That was on my end. The URL is now working fine. But the validator is still not working.

Comment: The syntax error is entirely unrelated to the code I posted. I have no idea what might cause it but it is *not the code posted in my answer*.

Comment: thats correct. my bad. validator doesnt work though.

Comment: @John: You haven't given me anything to go on here though. Sorry to hear it doesn't work! Your *original question* has been answered, perhaps you'll need to ask a new question for the next problem. Include the *actual HTML output* Flask produces, and what the validator states is wrong.

Comment: Maybe you can check the validator. Heres the URL to the validator `dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/validation/validator` and here is my link http://blabbybird.herokuapp.com/images/I+didnt+want+to+be+embarrassed%2C+so+I%7Cclaimed+that+I+had+a+lot+of+work+to+do.%7CI+said+I+could+easily+find+a+date+even%7Cbetter+than+his+if+I+wanted+to.+I+also%7Ctold+him+that+his+date+was+ugly.+I%7Cachieved+power+to+help+me+feel%7Cconfident%3B+however%2C+I+embarrassed+my%7Cfriend+and+his+date.+Although+this+lie%7Chelped+me+at+the+time%2C+since+then+it+has%7Cmade+me+look+down+on+myself.%7C%7C%7C%7C

Comment: @John: note that I am a volunteer here, could you adjust your expectations for help accordingly? I cannot even get the validator produce working sample output for you, it looks as if Twitter doesn't like the long URL charts produces.

Comment: @John: Google's chart domain has a `robots.txt` that *prohibits* Twitter from using charts as photo cards.